# Rails Docker Image Deployed on Kubernetes Cluster. Safe to run rake:db:migrate on every Dockerfile build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to determine where to put the `rake db:migrate` in our deployment. I have it currently in the Dockerfile.

The basic setup we have now is.

Dev works on Rails App -> Push to Repo -> Build/Scan/Push Image to Docker Registry -> Deploy to K8s cluster.

Currently in this workflow, every time it Builds it will do a `rake db:migrate`.

Is this reasonable?

Comment: How can you successfully run `rake db:migrate` at build time? Are you running your DB in the same container?

Comment: That's a good question. When it was in a docker compose file it had the db listed as a dependency so the build went first. This deployment on k8s needs the db as a dependency as well. Currently the deploy is not set up that way. But we already have a pod with postgres running. It's just not officially a dependency yet. My main question was, if I keep running rake db:migrate from a freshly built container will it mess with my data.

Comment: Makes sense. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is reasonable if you use a RollingUpdate strategy for your kubernetes deployment.

In a case where you are even running multiple replicas of your rails app, you should be fine.

For example, if you are running 5 replicas, and use RollingUpdate, when you deploy a new image of your rails app, all 5 replica deployments will run rake db:migrate, but only the first run will actually apply the migration. The other runs will do nothing.

As long as you use RollingUpdate, this will allow some time to pass between replica deployments, so you won’t run into database locking issues etc, that you might experience deploying all replicas at the same time.